# dpkg-reconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, apt, vagrant, dpkg

I am building a provisioning script for a `ubuntu vagrant vm`, on a `ubuntu host`, both `12.10 64bit` When installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-xsl graphviz php-pear unison
```

I get the warning:

```
dpkg-reconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No file or directory
```

have tried searching but results are throwing up every other error with apt-get possible, can't find out how to supress the warning above. The installs work, but the warning above is causing error lines in the vagrant up stdout.

Anybody any idea what could be the cause or how to suppress the warning

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer was to set the `perl:locale`'s as per [this](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_in_Debian):

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This solves the issue, but does add unwanted time to the `vagrant up` provisioning.

Comment: This alone did not work for me. I still got the warning until I implemented @kenorb's `70debconf` commenting-out fix for preconfigure.

Comment: My question is: Is it fine to ignore these warnings? @Coombesy

Comment: @MarcoPrins Yes, you can safely ignore warnings like "stdin: is not a tty" or "dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: No such file or directory". One of numerous confirmations around can be found, e.g. here https://www.ikusalic.com/blog/2013/10/03/vagrant-intro/

Answer (score 120):

I got the error message to go away by putting the following in my provisioning script, prior to any `apt-get` calls:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

This makes `debconf` use a frontend that expects no interactive input at all, preventing it from even trying to access `stdin`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Most config management applications (SaltStack, Puppet, etc) leverage this for non-interactive package installs.

Comment: Correct answer, I second that.

Comment: It doesn't work for dpkg-preconfigure though.

Comment: `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` worked for me at the `dpkg-preconfigure` stage

Answer (score 10):

Run this command:

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

to see if you've this file. If so, the solution is to comment out the `DPkg` line which prevents pre-configuring all packages with `debconf` before they are installed.

So add these commands to your provision file:

```
sudo ex +"%s@DPkg@//DPkg" -cwq /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure debconf -f noninteractive -p critical
```

Otherwise if you don't care about this file, simply remove it:

```
sudo rm -v /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf
```

Here are few other commands to consider, but I don't think they do anything useful:

```
sudo dpkg-preconfigure -f noninteractive -p critical
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: This is what finally worked for me on OSX Yosemite Vagrant and Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You may still need to change the shell Vagrant uses.

Comment: Messing with this file was the only thing that worked for me (obviously ignoring the "redirect stderr" suggestions, which I think is bad advice).  I elected to use a before/after pair of provisioning steps to temporarily include the `--frontend=noninteractive` option in the command defined in the file. `sudo sed -i 's/\(dpkg-preconfigure\) --apt/\1 --frontend=noninteractive --apt/' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` before, and `sudo sed -i 's/ --frontend=noninteractive//' /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf` after.

Answer (score 5):

Bash redirection works fine for stdout and stderr.

To redirect the error stream, use the following:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-xsl graphviz php-pear unison 2> /dev/null
```

To redirect both stdout (messages that are not errors/warnings) and stderr both, use:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-xsl graphviz php-pear unison &> /dev/null
```

That is a shortcut available in bash for this:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-xsl graphviz php-pear unison > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5-xsl graphviz php-pear unison 1> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Below, we can clearly see that file descriptor 1 is stdout, 2 stderr, 3 stdin.

```
$ ls -l /dev/std*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 18 19:03 /dev/stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 18 19:03 /dev/stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Apr 18 19:03 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

So for what you are saying you want to do, you should only need the very first command I gave.

Comment: I want to be able to echo the normal stdout from apt-get. But you may have me on the right track... i'll try sending just the stderr to the bit-bucket - cheers
edit: we both commented at the same time lol - cheers (again)

Comment: I edited the post. See the very last line.